# Read from the Database and Publish the message to a topic at the same time

Tags: java

I have a requirement wherein I need to read certain records from a database and then publish the records to a topic. There is no validation/requirement which is to be done after the messages are retrieved from the database. Which is a better approach ?

- Read all the required data from the database and then publish each
  message at a time.
- Read each row and then publish it at the same
  time.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about here?

Comment: The number might go and beyond 1M

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly would want to go with the second option, namely reading each row and then publishing that row.  Actually, you might have some sort of buffer, say 4KB, which you would fill with messages before writing them out.

The main reason for this is that if you read all messages, it won't scale well if you have many users/sessions concurrently running.  The reason is that the JVM only has so much memory and bandwidth, and clogging it with every message for each request can drag it down or crash it easily.